# A Year 9 competitive examination question

Tags: ratio

Hi this is my first time posting a question here. I came across this question in a competitive examination and couldn’t solve it:

£280 is shared among 3 children based on ratio of age

Beatrice turns x years old on Monday

Charlie turns y years old on Tuesday

Ava turns z years old on Wednesday

If money is given out on Monday, Charlie gets twice the money of Ava
If Tuesday, Charlie gets thrice the money of Beatrice
If Wednesday, Beatrice receives £50

Parents give out money on Thursday, calculate  money received by Ava

Please ask if you need any clarifications. Thanks in advance

Comment: Say Beatrice turns $x$ years old on Monday, ... and then edit your question to show that you have made an effort. Elementary questions with no efforts are usually not very well received on this site.

Comment: Ok I’ll try. thank you for your reminder

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-

From the following table try to write the corresponding formulas

$$ \begin{bmatrix} **       & Su  & Mo  & Tu  & We & Th \\
                   Beatrice & x-1 & x   & x   & x  & x  \\
                   Charlie  & y-1 & y-1 & y   & y  & y  \\
                   Ava      & z-1 & z-1 & z-1 & z  & z  \\  \end{bmatrix} 
$$